# Where is my mistake in deriving this probability?

Tags: probability

$X$ and $Y$ are independent Uniform(0,1) random variables. I want to find $\mathbb{P}(XY < \frac{1}{2})$

I proceeded like this:

$$\mathbb{P}(XY < \frac{1}{2}) = \mathbb{P}(X < \frac{1}{2Y}) $$

If $Y$ was discrete we could write

$$\mathbb{P}(X < \frac{1}{2Y}) = \sum_y \mathbb{P}(X < \frac{1}{2Y}|Y = y) \mathbb{P}(Y = y) $$

So in a continuous case this becomes an integral:

$$\mathbb{P}(X < \frac{1}{2Y}) = \int_{0}^1\frac{1}{2y}*1 dy$$

But the integral doesnt converge. Where did I go wrong? I would be most grateful if you show a mistake in my derivations instead of just solving the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when $Y$ is smaller than $1/2$?  Then the outcome of $X \in [0,1]$ does not matter, because we are guaranteed that $XY < 1/2$ and the probability of this event is $1$.  This is why your integral fails to converge, because in the expression $$\int_{y=0}^1 \frac{1}{2y} \, dy,$$ the integrand $1/(2y)$ becomes *too large* when $y$ is "close" to $0$.  You need to take this into account.

The correct expression is $$\Pr[XY < 1/2] = \Pr[X < 1/(2Y)] = \int_{y=0}^{1/2} \Pr[X < 1] f_Y(y) \, dy + \int_{y=1/2}^1 \Pr[X < 1/(2y)] f_Y(y) \, dy.$$  The first integral is just $1/2$.  The second integral is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

It these cases, a drawing will result always very useful and self explaining.

$$\mathbb{P}\Bigg[XY<\frac{1}{2}\Bigg]=\mathbb{P}\Bigg[Y<\frac{1}{2X}\Bigg]$$

[image]

The requested probability is the colored area:

$$\mathbb{P}\Bigg[XY<\frac{1}{2}\Bigg]=0.5+\int_{0.5}^1 \frac{1}{2x}dx=0.5(1+\log2)$$

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks! sadly I cant accept two answers